# calculate distance of a path

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to calculate the distance of a path when the distances are given like this:
AB = 8, AC = 4, AD = 8, AE = 11, BC = 5, BD = 6 , BE = 3, etc
So if the path followed is ABE, the total distance will be 8 + 3 =11.

I tried the following code:

```
'dictionaries with paths and distances 
distances = {"AB" : 8, "AC" : 4, "AD" :  8, "AE" : 11, "BC" : 5, "BD" : 6 , "BE" : 3}

'calculation path ABE
path = "AB-BE"
distance = 0 

for character in path:
   for key, value in distances.items():
      if key == path:
         distance = distance + value

print (distance)
```

but my distance remains 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for character in path:` you iterate the string `path` char by char. That means that in the first iteration, the value of character is `A` and not `AB`. Additionally, since the keys of `distances` are 2-grans none of them will be equal to path. That is `key == path` will never be `True`.

I suggest splitting path and then iterating them over:

```py
path_splits = path.split("-")
distance = 0
for path_split in path_splits:
   distance +=distances[path_split]

print (distance)
```

If `path_split` does not exist in `distances` an error will occur but that a good sign to check either the `path` or the `distances`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
distance = sum(distances[p] for p in path.split('-'))
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> sum(distances[p] for p in 'AB-BC'.split('-'))
13
>>> sum(distances[p] for p in 'AB-BE'.split('-'))
11
```